# "Ansatz" isn't thoroughly defined in German dictionaries!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, german-to-english, synonym

What's the meaning of *"Ansatz"* in these sentences? Could someone paraphrase them in German?:

> 1. Der **Ansatz** für Multikulti ist gescheitert, absolut gescheitert!
> 2. **Ansätze** zu einem besseren Hochwasserschutz, wie etwa die Leitlinien der Länderarbeitsgemeinschaft Wasser vom November 1995, würden auf regionaler Ebene immer noch ignoriert.
> 3. Die Förderalismuskommission hat bislang noch keinen konkreten **Reformansatz** geliefert.
> 4. Schon damals begann er in **Ansätzen**, von mir Dankbarkeit zu fordern.
>
> I overlooked this one oddity: 5. Die Gelegenheit für diesen **Investmentansatz** ist günstig.

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/?search=ansatz

Answer (score 10):

Oh dear, this is one of those poor words that tend to get thoroughly violated in today's media, marketing and political speak.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ansatz) lists the following meanings:

> 1. (Technik) das Angesetzte; Verlängerungsstück
> 2. erstes sichtbares Zeichen; Spross, Anflug von etwas
> 3. a        das Ansetzen
>      b     Schicht, die sich angesetzt hat
> 4. (Anatomie) Stelle, wo ein Körperteil, Glied ansetzt, beginnt
> 5. erstes Anzeichen
> 6. a       (Musik) bestimmte Stellung und Spannung der Lippen beim Anblasen von Blasinstrumenten
>      b     (Musik) Art der Erzeugung von Tönen beim Singen
> 7. (Wirtschaft) Veranschlagung, Voranschlag, Kalkulation
> 8. (Mathematik) Umsetzung einer Textaufgabe in eine mathematische Form
> 9. (Chemie) Zusammenstellung der Bestandteile für eine chemische Reaktion

Unfortunately, the definition that's missing is the one that seems to be most prevalent these days. It's an extension of Nr. 8 and means "Lösungsansatz", "Lösungsversuch", "Lösungsmethode" and is used in scientific and political contexts. Often with the verb "verfolgen", e.g. "Wir haben in den letzten Monaten einen neuen Ansatz verfolgt, um dieses Problem zu lösen."

Now, your sentences in reverse order:

> Schon damals begann er **in Ansätzen**, von mir Dankbarkeit zu fordern.

Paraphrase: Schon damals begann er, von mir Dankbarkeit zu fordern. ("In Ansätzen" - *with* preposition - is an intensifying phrase that is unnecessary here) [meaning Nr. 2]

> Die Förderalismuskommission hat bislang noch keinen konkreten **Reformansatz** geliefert.

Die Förderalismuskommission hat bislang noch keinen konkreten Reformvorschlag geliefert. [this is the extra "modern" meaning I was talking about - Note, that though "Vorschlag" is a synonym here, it has *nothing* to do with meaning 7, although it seems to border on it]

> **Ansätze** zu einem besseren Hochwasserschutz, wie etwa die Leitlinien der Länderarbeitsgemeinschaft Wasser vom November 1995, würden auf regionaler Ebene immer noch ignoriert.

Paraphrase: Vorschläge zu einem besseren Hochwasserschutz, wie etwa die Leitlinien der Länderarbeitsgemeinschaft Wasser vom November 1995, würden auf regionaler Ebene immer noch ignoriert. [see above]

> Der **Ansatz** für Multikulti ist gescheitert, absolut gescheitert!

Paraphrase: Multikulti ist gescheitert, absolut gescheitert!
...Sorry, this sentence is just a mess - I suspect the author wants to say something like "Versuch" or something. This is a great example for a certain creepy ghostlike quality of some words in public speech. You somehow get the gist, or can kind of "feel" what's supposed to be meant, but can't really nail the meaning down. (Same problem as with "nachhaltig" *cringe*)

Comment: I wished I could give you an extra upvote for "nachhaltig".

Comment: Beim Hochwasserschutz würde ich Nr. 2 (=5) wählen: erste, sichtbare (An-)zeichen. Der Multikultisatz unterschlägt ein Gebiet, und vermischt mit der Verniedlichungsform ist es dann schwer zu sagen, was ernsthaft gemeint ist: "Der multikulturell orientierte Ansatz der Jugendarbeit ist gescheitert" könnte ein vollständiger Satz sein "stramm deutschtümelnde Ansätze dagegen erstürmen im Stechschritt höchste Höhen." Das 'für' ist das 3. Problem des Satzes, fällt mir auf. Es soll subtil transportieren, dass der Sprecher nicht dafür ist (Multikulti), sondern dagegen.

Comment: @userunknown: Hmm, nicht sicher, ob die Leitlinien als sichtbare Anzeichen durchgehen :)
Beim "für" würde ich nicht zu viel Intention reininterpretieren - ich verstehe es eher so, dass es subtil, aber unbeabsichtigt, transportiert, wie große Schwierigkeiten Frau Merkel in der freien Rede mit Präpositionen hat...
Im Übrigen hoffe ich, dass es auch in einem solchen Zusammenhang noch Mittelwege gibt, die nicht zwingend im Stechschritt beschritten werden müssen.

Comment: @Mac: Für Dich und mich sind Leitlinien erstmal geduldiges Papier, aber für waschechte Bürokraten sind Gesetzentwürfe etwas vorläufiges, ein Versuch, aber verabschiedete Leitlinien sind schon das fertige Produkt - mehr produziert ein Bürokrat eh nicht. Die Leitlinie den Deich zu erhöhen ist wichtiger, als die Erhöhung des Deiches selbst.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to give you appropriate synonyms to rephrase your examples:

> 1. Der **Grundgedanke** für Multikulti ist gescheitert, absolut gescheitert!
> 2. **Grundsätze** zu einem besseren Hochwasserschutz, wie etwa die Leitlinien der Länderarbeitsgemeinschaft Wasser vom November 1995, würden auf regionaler Ebene immer noch ignoriert.
> 3. Die Förderalismuskommission hat bislang noch keinen konkreten **Ausgangspunkt für eine Reform** geliefert.
> 4. Schon damals begann er **andeutungsweise**, von mir Dankbarkeit zu fordern.

For furthers synonyms and meanings see also [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ansatz).

Answer (score 2):

1. Der Versuch Multikulti ist gescheitert, [...]
2. Erste Schritte zu einem besseren [...]
3. Die Föderalismuskomission hat bislang noch keinen konkreten Reformvorschlag geliefert.
4. Schon damals begann er versuchsweise / teilweise, von mir Dankbarkeit zu fordern.

Answer (score 2):

The first three examples can be rephrased with **"(gewählte/begonnene) Herangehensweise**". Here "Ansatz" is used like in "zu einem Sprung ansetzen" or "zu einem Schlag ansetzen" and describes the starting/preparation of a process. It emphasises the fact that the chosen approach has just begun and is far from completed.

With example 4 I am with Takkat ("in Ansätzen" = "andeutungsweise"), again emphasizing the state of non-completion.

Answer (score 1):

- Lösungsversuch
- Idee für eine Lösung
- Anfang eines Plans

Diese Bedeutung von "Ansatz" ist Lesart 2 im [Wiktionary-Artikel zu "Ansatz"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ansatz).

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "Ansatz" has about the same meaning as the English word "approach": the way you deal with something.

Ansatz comes from "ansetzen", which is: to place a tool before you start working.